# Pick image from gallery and set in imageview with same size

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to pick the image from gallery and set the image with same size in imageview in activity but i wrote code but its not displaying on with same size in imageview. its displaying small. How to achieve with same size.

Here its set size of imageview

```
mainImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(270,this),VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(280, this)));

mainImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.border);
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
linearLayout.addView(mainImageView);
```

Intent for pick image from gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),10);

if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
            {             
                Uri contentUri = data.getData();          
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };         
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);         
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);         
                cursor.moveToFirst();         
                imageUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));

                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                mainImageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);

                if(tempBitmap!=null)
                {
                    isModel = false;
                    VMAdjustFrame.issaved = false;
                    isPhotofromAccount = false;
                    isPhotoChanged = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`mainImageView.setLayoutParams().height = 270`
`mainImageView.setLayoutParams().width= 270`

size of image

remove this and try code above 
`mainImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(270,this),VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(280, this)));`